# How do you revoke access to the Keychain on Macosx?

Tags: macos, keychain

Sometimes an application might request access to the keychain to access or store passwords for the user. The passwords themselves can be managed with MacOSX's keychain program. However, how can I manage the permissions of the applications which can access the keychain?

More specifically, I allowed an application to access the keychain, and now want to revoke that access. I've searched keychain's help and there doesn't seem anything related to the applications' priviledges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it say “So-and-so wants to use the login keychain; please enter the password”? I think that unlocks the keychain as a whole, and once it’s open any app can create entries. Access is controlled on individual entries, and only the app that created it and other authorized apps can read the password.

For example, here’s the access control for one entry in my keychain:

[image: Screenshot of Keychain Access]